# Site Workflow Not Working With Contribute Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have set up a form where when someone presses the "Submit" button it initiates a site workflow to create a list item. It all works well when I (full control permissions) do it, but if someone with contribute permissions tries, it fails. I tried adding an impersonation step, but that doesn't seem to be working either. Also, I am trying to record the person who created the list item, and the impersonation step uses my name (workflow author) for "Created By."

Any suggestions as to what I could've possible done wrong, or what I should try to do/add? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple answer is No.

As you can see the checkboxes in workflow property, you can set the trigger to be

trigger itself when item added or modified.
manually start by users.
For the read-only user, they are not able to click the "start a workflow" button. Also, these users do not have permission to add or modify list item.

You can configure your workflow with "impersonation step". In this way, the workflow will be running under the account of "workflow creator" instead of the user trigger the workflow. However, even you applied "impersonation step", the read-only user still not able to trigger a workflow
```